# Live or console like CSS execution in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have googled, but found no satisfactory answer.

Is there a way to execute a CSS selector live in the browser in the same way you can with JavaScript in the console?

I know I can modify the CSS in the Styles pain, but this doesn't seem to let me add psuedo selectors such as :first-of-type. It also doesn't appear to show all tags affected or the tag set returned by a selector.

Is there a way I can execute `section.blah:first-of-type` and see the returned or affected elements?

I'm using only Chrome right now but can use FF or whatever if it gives me this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In the Elements tab, you can search with selector syntax.

If you search for

```
.myclass
```

you will find elements that have class="myclass"

I think that this is the closest that you can get to what you are asking

Go to the elements tab, and press ctrl+F (for find). in the example below, enter div.answer

[image: demo on stack overflow page]

to the right of the search string, you see "1 of 3" stating that 3 elements met your criteria. The current one is highlighted. and you can go up & down thru the items with the arrows.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but I don't quite understand. How do I search for `.myclass`?

Comment: @NathanBarley: what vals said. Open the Elements panel, hit `Ctrl+F`, and type your selector (`.myclass`) into the search field, then press `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

Acctually you can do that just via editing the Styles pane.
You have to select a parent first(html in my case).

[image]

The result is:

[image]

In this way, chrome will show all affection instantly. Not just highlight the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery in your page then you can do:

```
$("section.blah:first-of-type");
```

Executing that in the browser console will show you a list of elements that jquery matched.

Better yet you can assign it to a variable and traverse it programatically.